# How do you disable/remove a CDN's default css from your application?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, cdn

I am integrating a date picker component in my tailwindcss app, and to do that I have to add the css and javascript CDN links. The problem now is the css gotten from the CDN is overriding my own css thereby messing up my app. Is there a way to make the css gotten from the CDN to just apply to the datepicker component?

Comment: import your own css after the cdn css?

Comment: No, CSS is a global thing, so if you're loading from a CDN, I don't think you can only apply it for a specific component. The only solution here is probably to download the CDN CSS and manually import it with the help of webpack or something like that to have "scoped" CSS

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your code but you should be able to revert the non-datepicker styles like this:

```css
*:not(.date-picker, .date-picker *) {
  all: revert;
}
```

Set all properties to browser default for that element, on all elements that are not .date-picker or any descendant of .date-picker